# Can someone help me understand the code below

Tags: python, list, dictionary, enumerate

I want to understand how the code below works can someone help me through this
See the code below

```
keys = ['name', 'age', 'food'] values = ['Monty', 42, 'spam'] 
dict = {} 
for index, item in enumerate(keys):
        dict[item] = values[index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys = ['name', 'age', 'food'] 
values = ['Monty', 42, 'spam'] 

d = {}

for key, value in zip(keys,values):
    d[key] = value

print (d)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Monty', 'age': 42, 'food': 'spam'}
```

You code example was, indeed, quite complicated. This `zip()` method makes a list of lists (nested list).

To comment your code:

```
keys = ['name', 'age', 'food'] 
values = ['Monty', 42, 'spam'] 
dic = {} 
#index is common to keys and values lists, item is the element at index for keys list
for index, item in enumerate(keys):
        #You set the key item with the element found at the corresponding index in values
        dic[item] = values[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the `for` loop, creates an element of the dictionary `dict` with the key `item` and the value `values` with index `index`